# Rotating and moving an image in a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

I would like to move and rotate an image of a ball in a  element.  The ball is 68x68 and the canvas is 300x200.  The ball moves along the x and y axis, flipping its x and y velocity when it hits a wall - all of this works.  I just can't figure how to do rotation on top of the movement.

My draw() function, which I call through window.setInterval every 30ms, looks something like this:

```
  var draw = function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate(ball_radians);
    ctx.drawImage(ball_img, x, y);
    ctx.restore();

    // calculate new x, y, and ball_radians
  }
```

This makes the ball fly around the screen, so clearly I'm doing something wrong.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Translate the context to the point on the canvas that the object should rotate about.
2. Rotate the context.
3. Either:

   - Translate the context by the negative offset within the object for the center of rotation, and then draw the object at `0,0`, or
   - Draw the image using the negative offset within the object for the center of rotation.

e.g.

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate( canvasLocX, canvasLocY );
ctx.rotate( ballRotationInRadians );
ctx.drawImage( ball_img, -ballCenterX, -ballCenterY );
ctx.restore();
```

Note that if you need absolute speed, instead of saving and restoring the canvas (handling many properties that you didn't change) you can just undo your work:

```
ctx.translate( canvasLocX, canvasLocY );
ctx.rotate( ballRotationInRadians );
ctx.drawImage( ball_img, -ballCenterX, -ballCenterY );
ctx.rotate( -ballRotationInRadians );
ctx.translate( -canvasLocX, -canvasLocY );
```

*The previous bit of premature optimization has been blindly parroted from someone else; I have not personally benchmarked to verify that it is correct.*

**Edit**: I've added a mocked up working example of this here: http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_beachball.html