# moving a turtle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an assignment with which i have multiple problems.

Simply put we need to move a turtle on a canvas forwards/backwards rotating it right/left with a given amount.

The turtle can leave a "trace" (a colored line or something) behind him when moving and when he reaches the end of the canvas it has to appear on the other side

now one of my problems is how can i move the turtle without redrawing the whole canvas, because i can't lose the turtles "trace" when he moves

the other thing is that i have no problem moving it in the 4 "normal" directions and appearing and the other side but i think we need to be able to rotate it any amount of degrees and move it in that direction and i don't really know how to do this

my code is not very advanced for these reasons i only have the canvas and the form from which i get my parameters

i don't really know what else to say about it, if necessary i will include all the code i have

UPDATE:

i think for the first problem about redrawing the canvas i can use `clearRect(locX,locY,imgWidth,imgHeight)` so i clear the area where the image was and draw only the image next to it, but if i'm wrong i'm open for tips

Comment: I don't know about canvas, but an approach for the trail may be to store what have being draw each "frame", clear all canvas and redraw everything plus new position, store it and repeat ;) For rotating you can look into polar coordinates. An angle and a length. You know , vector math... There is this tutorial about vector, for processing though, that you might find useful http://natureofcode.com/book/chapter-1-vectors/

Comment: thx a lot for the help ... for the rotation i found a pretty similar post with the ball bouncing from the wall like at your link and he gives the finished one too but i couldn't really figure out where is he calculatint the new trajectory and path of the movement ... here is what i found [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697041/rotating-and-moving-an-image-in-a-canvas-element]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use 2 overlapping canvases to more easily display your turtle and your tracks.**

Put your tracks on the bottom canvas (no need to ever clear/erase this bottom canvas).

Put your turtle on the top canvas (always clear this canvas and redraw the turtle in its new position).

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="canvasBottom" width=300 height=200></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvasTop" width=300 height=200></canvas>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS used to overlap the 2 canvases:

```
#wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}
#canvasTop,#canvasBottom{
    position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#canvasTop{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

To rotate your turtle, check out this tutorial on how to combine context.translate and context.rotate to display a rotated object:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-transform-rotate-tutorial/

To move your turtle along a linear path, start out with this tutorial on how to animate an object:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-linear-motion-animation/